# Función que devuelva cuantos números impares existen de 0 a un numero x

Tags: javascript

En este ejercicio nuestra tarea es completar la función noParesDeContarImparesHasta. Esta función recibe un número X por parámetro y cuenta la cantidad de números impares que hay desde el número 0 hasta el número X (inclusive) y luego retorna ese valor. Para resolver la ejercitación debemos utilizar el for.

Como resultado me dan este ejemplo:

```
console.log(noParesDeContarImparesHasta(4)) // imprime por pantalla el valor 2, que se obtiene de contar 1 y 3. Los valores 0, 2 y 4 no los contabiliza por ser números pares.
```

```
    function noParesDeContarImparesHasta(numero){
        let conteo;
        for (let i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
        if ((i % 2) !== 0) {
            conteo = i;
        }
    }
    return conteo;
    }
    console.log(noParesDeContarImparesHasta(180));
```

Comment: Creo que es importante recalcar que resolver ese problema con ciclos for no es para nada eficiente ni útil más que para ejercitar la sintaxis de js. Personalmente considero que eso es lo último que se debe ejercitar. En fin, este [link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2004fa/lectures/lecture16.htm) te puede dar una idea de porqué no es eficiente (básicamente tiene complejidad `O(n)` cuando podría ser `O(1)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás contando mal simplemente, conteo es un contador, parte en 1 y se va sumando 1 cada vez que encuentra un impar.

El cambio está en el mismo `conteo`.

```js
function noParesDeContarImparesHasta(numero){
    let conteo = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= numero; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) !== 0) {
        conteo = conteo + 1;
    }
}
return conteo;
}
console.log(noParesDeContarImparesHasta(4));
```

Comment: `respuesta ++;`

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma mas eficiente de calcular eso.

```js
function contarImparesHasta(numero) {
     var cantidad = Math.ceil(numero / 2);
 
    return cantidad
}

// Pruebas
console.log(contarImparesHasta(3))
console.log(contarImparesHasta(4))
console.log(contarImparesHasta(10))
```

En tu funcion, si el numero es 1000, eso significa que tu funcion hace un bucle 1000 veces. Esto en calculo de performance se conoce como `O(N)`.

En el codigo de aqui arriba, no importa cual es el numero que ingreses, siempre se ejecutara una sola vez. Esto se conoce como `O(1)`

[EDIT]
Ahora noto que es un ejercicio donde te piden utilizar el for.
Dejo la respuesta igualmente, para que sepas que hay mejores formas de resolverlo que utilizando un `for`

Comment: Ya nada más porque me "hace ruido" la creación de esa variable... ¿y si solo devuelves el resultado directamente?

Comment: Agregaste el edit, pero cabe dejar claro... esto es una tarea. Le piden un formato, usar cosas, etc. El OP tiene 1 problema en particular, su problema no era que esto demora en procesar... su problema es que no calculaba bien las cosas.

Comment: Tienes razon @Excorpion. No se si es que no vi quer era una tarea donde si o si debe utilizar el for, o si ese requerimiento lo agregaron en un EDIT luego de mi primer respuesta. Si te parece, elimino mi respuesta.

Comment: No es necesario que la elimines creo... queda a tu discreción la verdad. Los edits puedes verlos siempre y verás que si lo dice.